# Jest test is throwing TypeError: is not a function when calling function with Require

Tags: javascript, express, jestjs

I am using `Jest` to test and cover my `express js` code. I have a file `default.js` which is exporting a simple function:

```
async function foo(req, res) {
  let out = {}
  // performs some computations

  res.send({
    file: 'Default',
    data:  out.data
  })
}

module.export = {foo}
```

This is then being called in `app.js`:

```
const def = require('./default')

app.get('/default/:a/:b' async (req, res) => {
  def.foo(req, res)
})
```

This works fine. However, when I try to create a test on the Handler function in `default.js` `Jest` throws this error:

```
TypeError: def.foo is not a function
```

This is my test file:

```
const def = require('./default')

describe('Default Test', function() {

  test('responds to /default/:a/:b', () => {
    const req = {
      params: {
        a: 'country',
        b: 'city'
      }
    }

    const res = {
      text: '',
      send: function(input) {
        this.text = input
      }
    }

    def.foo(req, res)

    expect(res.json).toEqual({
        file: 'Default',
      })
  })
})
```

Never mind that the test should fail with the `expect` function. But the test is failing at `default.foo` it is not finding this function. **Why is this?**

Comment: What is the project folder structure? If the test file and default.js are in different folders (as they should be), your require statement will fail since the path to default.js relative to app.js and the path to default.js relative to tests.js are different. In the test file you should use the absolute path or the path **relative to the test file**.